# SVG alignment and scroll not working

Tags: css, svg, scrollbar

I need to display SVG text in the same font size and if the length of the text varies, it should be horizontally scrollable. There are many questions like this on the web but there's no one answer that works, at least that I can find. I have put together pieces from the various answers as can be seen in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/user3052443/w3vyy0y1/3/). But it has problems in all of the browsers.

In FF, the left alignment is good but the scroll doesn't work at all.

In Chrome, the left alignment isn't even close and the scroll doesn't work.

In IE, it is almost the way I want it. The left alignment is a little off but the scrolling works.

Is it possible to have the text start at the same X position and the scrollbar to work for all browsers?

```
    <div style="display:block; margin:0 auto; height:100px; width:90%; border:2px solid #000; overflow-x:scroll;">
     <div style="display:inline-block">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
           xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
           width="100%" height="80"   
           onload="init(evt)"
           align="center"> 
            <rect id="rect1" x="20" y="10" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" stroke="red"/>
            <text id="text-to-resize"
              text-anchor="middle"
              x="170" y="50"
              font-family="Times New Roman" font-size="55">
              <tspan text-anchor="middle" dy="15">Some short text</tspan>
            </text>
      </svg>
     </div>
    </div>


    <div style="display:block; margin:0 auto; height:100px; width:90%; border:2px solid #000; overflow-x:scroll;">
     <div style="display:inline-block">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
           xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
           width="100%" height="80"   
           onload="init(evt)"
           align="center"> 
            <rect id="rect1" x="20" y="10" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" stroke="red"/>
            <text id="text-to-resize"
              text-anchor="middle"
              x="730" y="50"
              font-family="Times New Roman" font-size="55">
              <tspan text-anchor="middle" dy="15">Some Unknown Text that is too long to display without scrolling</tspan>
            </text>
      </svg>
     </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/ecmascript">
      function init(evt) {
          if ( window.svgDocument == null ) {
              svgDocument = evt.target.ownerDocument;
          }

          maximum_length = 300;
          my_text = svgDocument.getElementById('text-to-resize');

          for (var font_size=55; font_size>0; font_size--) {
              if(my_text.getComputedTextLength() < maximum_length){break;}
              my_text.setAttributeNS(null, "font-size", font_size);
          }
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you have another go at explaining what you are trying to achieve please? Because your question and your code don't seem to match. And I don't really understand what you are trying to do in your code either.

Comment: I'm trying to display text created with SVG. The text can vary in length. I show two boxes of text in the example to illustrate short and long text. The displayed text has problems depending upon the browser being used. For example, I just clicked on my jsfiddle link above in FF and the long text is not showing a horizontal scroller but if you open that in IE, it does. Please let me know if that is not clear and I will try again.

Comment: Does the font size changing code have anything to do with the problem?  If not, then please remove it to avoid confusion.

Comment: I removed that but it doesn't seem to have made a difference. Here is the updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/user3052443/w3vyy0y1/5/ It seems to be OK in IE but not in FF and Chrome where the scrolling doesn't work.

Comment: I think this is resolved now. There wasn't a closing </rect> and I changed the anchor to start. It seems to be working correctly here. Thank you for talking me through it. There is very little SVG support, that I can find, so your suggestions were very helpful.